# msgfmt not found though msgfmt is installed via package manager

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

I'm having trouble building Git from sources on an ARM dev-board running Armbian. Armbian is a Ubuntu Bionic derivative. Git fails at the `make test` recipe.

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/build/git-2.21.0/templates'
mkdir -p po/build/locale/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/ && msgfmt --check --statistics -o po/build/locale/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo po/pt_PT.po
/bin/sh: 1: msgfmt: not found
Makefile:2533: recipe for target 'po/build/locale/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo' failed
make: *** [po/build/locale/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo] Error 127
```

But:

```
$ apt-cache search msgfmt
libdist-zilla-plugin-localemsgfmt-perl - Dist::Zilla plugin to compile PO files with Locale::Msgfmt
liblocale-msgfmt-perl - pure Perl reimplementation of msgfmt
```

And:

```
$ apt-cache policy liblocale-msgfmt-perl
liblocale-msgfmt-perl:
  Installed: 0.15-1
  Candidate: 0.15-1
```

However:

```
$ command -v msgfmt
$
```

`hash -r` does not clear the problem. The problem does not exist on other machines I have, including Ubuntu and Fedora machines.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 10):

```
$ apt-file search bin/msgfmt
gettext: /usr/bin/msgfmt
$ sudo apt install gettext
```

`msgfmt` is part of `gettext`.

```
dpkg -L liblocale-msgfmt-perl
```

will show you that `liblocale-msgfmt-perl` doesn’t provide a `msgfmt` command (which does make its description misleading).

```
apt-cache search msgfmt
```

doesn’t find `gettext` because the `gettext` package’s description doesn’t mention it:

```
Description: GNU Internationalization utilities
 Interesting for authors or maintainers of other packages or programs
 which they want to see internationalized.
```